# How to handle a file which has been passed as a string from backend in react?

Tags: reactjs, django, excel, rest, file

in my react app, i have a button that triggers a request to backend Django. In the response of that request, there is a excel file but it has passed as a string like the image I added in the bottom. do you have any idea how should i handle that file to be downloaded on users system? [picture of the response i'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtaNp.png)